# Dell Laptop Screen Blanks When On Battery

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Dell laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise that works fine when connected to the docking station with two connected external monitors. When I attempt to use it in standalone mode, the screen comes on but blanks itself after five seconds or so. The computer is still running (is not going into hibernation) and, if I type carefully, I can still log in to my account. I'm trying to discover why the screen is blanking and fix it so I can use the laptop as a laptop.

**Technical Info:**

- Dell Precision 3510
- Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1709, build 16299.1625)
- New OEM battery installed in November 2019 - the problem did appear only after the new battery was installed
- The battery indicates 100% charge and no issues
- If I enable the laptop speakers, I hear the Windows Default "Device Disconnect" sound immediately before the screen blanks
- I have changed the Power & Sleep settings to "Never" turn the screen off (battery or plugged in), and "Never" sleep (battery or plugged in). The problem still persists
- Oddly, the problem does not occur if I boot into Safe Mode (with networking)
- Suspecting a driver issue, I have updated all the drivers especially the Intel HD Graphics 530 and the ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery driver. The problem still persists

My guess is a battery issue, perhaps a "sense" control signal from the battery indicating its power state? Since the problem does not exist in Safe Mode, there seems to be a system setting I could change but I'm out of ideas.

I'm hoping someone with knowledge of laptop batteries or similar issues can give me a bit of guidance.

Comment: Would it be switching to an external display?

Comment: Try Balanced Power plan (most adaptable in my experience) and update the Power Driver. BIOS may need updating as well.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It's not connected to an external display, so it might be attempting to switch to one. But if I connected an external display, that would defeat the purpose of using it as a laptop with the integrated display. It's an interesting question, and I may give that a try to see it an external display (not routed through a docking station) would stay on.

Comment: @John The Power Options plan is currently set to Balanced, though I changed the defaults to Never for the display and sleep to potentially solve the problem. I have changed back to the defaults and the problem persists.

Comment: Try allowing the Screen to power save after some interval - not Never. Sleep (Suspend) should be OK. I have this set for 3 hours on battery.

Comment: You can force a laptop to switch to an external display, even if there isn't any.